# Where are methods of `__del__`, `__bytes__`,`__bool__` defined for class 'object'

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, methods

I am reading python official documentation word by word.

In the 3.3. Special method names [3.3.1. Basic customization](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization)

It does specify 16 special methods under `object` basic customization, I collect them as following:

```
In [47]: bc =['__new__', '__init__', '__del__', '__repr__', '__str__', '__bytes__', 
'__format__', '__eq__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__eq__', 
'__ne__', '__ge__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__bool__']
In [48]: len(bc)
Out[48]: 16
```

The problem is that there's three of them are not `object`'s valid attributes

```
In [50]: for attr in bc:
    ...:     if hasattr(object,attr):
    ...:         pass
    ...:     else:
    ...:         print(attr)
    ...:
__del__
__bytes__
__bool__
```

Object is a base for all classes. [2. Built-in Functions — Python 3.6.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=object#object)

It has no recursive base classes.

Where are methods of `__del__`, `__bytes__`,`__bool__` defined for class 'object'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where are methods of `__del__`, `__bytes__`, `__bool__` defined for class 'object'?

They aren't defined on `object`. These are special methods you can implement yourself on classes.

The misunderstanding probably happened because the documentation says `object.__bool__`, but the `object.` there just means that it's a method on the object (in the sense of "instance") **if implemented**. 
Likewise the later examples on that documentation page list it also shows special methods for metaclasses with `class.__subclasscheck__`. That doesn't mean that it's always implemented, more like **if implemented it's available on the class**.

Answer (score 0):

`__del__` absolutely must not exist for `object` - its very presence in a class changes how the garbage collector treats its instances, so having this method on `object` would make it impossible for any class to not have it.

`__bool__` is only needed if you want to override the default behavior of treating objects as truthy in a boolean context.  `object` has no need to override that behavior.

I'm not sure what's up with `__bytes__`, I think it defaults to `__str__` if not present (or something similar).